# C# / Java Compress JPG image

Tags: java, c#, image, bitmap, compression

I need to replicate this code in C# but I have yet to find a good method.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

Bitmap d;
this.d.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, localByteArrayOutputStream);
Byte[] image = localByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

I am sending my own image to a server and it needs to be in the same format as this Java code makes.
How would this be possible in C#? Is there such thing as android.graphics.bitmap.CompressFormat or something equivalent that the server would accept?

Comment: this question is not about recommending or finding a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource. Furthermore, while there could be several ways to achieve what the question asks, it doesn't attract any opinionated answer since it doesn't ask "what's the best way to do it?". IMHO, this question asks about the usage (or existence) of an API feature within a specific Framework which is a typical programming question in SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty easy to achieve this in the .Net Framework with the aid of a couple of classes in the `System.Drawing` and `System.Drawing.Imaging` namespace. You don't even need to deal with low level stuff such as byte arrays...here's an example that takes a input file path and outputs the results to a different file...

```
        string inputFile = @"in.jpg";
        string outputFile = @"out.jpg";

        Bitmap inputPhoto = new Bitmap(inputFile);
        ImageCodecInfo decoder = null;

        ImageCodecInfo[] decoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo c in decoders)
        {
            if (c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid)
            {
                decoder = c;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder encoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

        EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(encoder, 70L);

        encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
        inputPhoto.Save(outputFile, decoder, encoderParams);
```

This does exactly what you want, however, if you don't have access to the file system you can always chuck the byte array in a `MemoryStream` object and use a different overload of the `Bitmap` class's constructor that takes in a `Stream` object